# Before start of result set running multiple sql

Tags: java, sql, resultset

I'm currently working on an application for a restaurant. The idea for the code I'm currently working on is that it gets the name from a combobox and inserts a receipt into the database whith the employee number of the person who is working on it. The code whith which I'm trying to do it is:

```
    RestaurantOrder sqlRestaurantOrder = new RestaurantOrder();
    ActionListener printReceiptListner;
    printReceiptListner = (ActionEvent) -> {
        int ID = Integer.parseInt(input1.getText());
        try {
            SystemManager manager = new SystemManager();
            ResultSet rs = manager.stmt.executeQuery(sqlRestaurantOrder.setIdSql(ID));

            while (rs.next()) {

                double totalPrice = rs.getDouble("sumprice");
                if (ID > 0) {
                    Receipt receiptSql = new Receipt();
                    String firstName = (String) cb.getSelectedItem();
                    String checkoutDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                    ResultSet rs2 = manager.stmt.executeQuery(receiptSql.getEmployeeId(firstName));
                    int employeeId = rs2.getInt("id");

                    while (rs2.next()) {

                    Receipt receiptSql2 = new Receipt();
                    ResultSet rs3 = manager.stmt.executeQuery(receiptSql2.SetStatusReceipt(employeeId, checkoutDate, ID, totalPrice));
                    while (rs3.next()) {
                    }
                    }

                }
            }

        } catch (SQLException k) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, k.getMessage());
        }
    };
```

The statements are:

```
public class Receipt {

    public String sql;
    public String sql2;

    public String getEmployeeId(String firstName){
        return sql2 = "SELECT id FROM employee WHERE firstName = '" + firstName + "';";
    }

    public String SetStatusReceipt(int employeeId, String checkoutDate, int id, double totalPrice){
        return sql = "INSERT INTO `receipt` (`employeeId`, `price`, `restaurantOrderId`, `checkoutDate`) VALUES (" + employeeId + " , " + totalPrice + ", " + id + ", " + checkoutDate + ");";
    };

}
```

I'm getting the error before start of result set which I looked up what it means but I can't get it fixed at the moment. Help will be appreciated.

If I forgot to post more important code let me know I'll update it

Comment: Please post the stacktrace of the error you are seeing.

Comment: just a suggestion, its better if you make separate calls to get the combo box and set the receipt, it would be much cleaner and easy to handle exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call [`ResultSet.next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next--) before you are able to access the fields of that `ResultSet`. So you need to move your assignment of `employeeId` into your `while` loop:

```
while (rs2.next()) {
    int employeeId = rs2.getInt("id");
```

From the documentation of `ResultSet.next()`:

> A `ResultSet` cursor is initially positioned before the first row; the first call to the method `next` makes the first row the current row; the second call makes the second row the current row, and so on.